# How do I test for a non-zero exit status of a command in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, exit-code

I have a script that checks the exit status of the following function:

```
function is_git_repository {                                                    
    git branch &> /dev/null                                                     
}
```

Which returns `0` if you're in a git repo, and `128` if you're not.

I have no problem testing to see if the return value is `0`; the following works as expected:

```
if is_git_repository ; then 
    echo you are in a git repo
else 
    echo you are NOT in a git repo
fi
```

But it's when I'm trying to test for an exit status that is anything OTHER than `0` when I'm running into problems. I've tried the following, but none of them work:

1. `if [[ "$(is_git_repository)" != "0" ]] ; ...` always evaluates to true ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6241286/1094541))
2. `if [[ "$(is_git_repository)" -ne "0" ]] ; ...` always evaluates to false
3. `if [[ "$(is_git_repository)" != 0 ]] ; ...` always evaluates to true
4. `if [[ "$(is_git_repository)" -ne 0 ]] ; ...` always evaluates to false
5. `if [[ ! "$(is_git_repository)" ]] ; ...` always evaluates to true
6. `if !is_git_repository ; ...` just echoes the command back to me, but without the bang (wtf?)

What is the correct way to check for a non-zero exit status of a command in an if statement?

Comment: You seem to be looking for $?

Comment: The "source" you linked to was neither the accepted nor the highest voted answer for the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I soon figured out that `if ! is_git_repository ; then ...` works as intended (look under **7.1.2.1. Testing exit status** in [Introduction to if](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html)), but why? I would have expected that #1 would work at the very least, but I don't know why it doesn't.

Also, what is up with #6?!

Comment: When you say `"$(is_git_repository)"` you get back the *standard output* of the command, not the *exit status*. You redirect stdout and stderr, so that's always the empty string which is always not equal to the string "0". bash is whitespace sensitive so the `!` needs to stand alone. As @devnull mentions, if you want the exit status you need the `$?` variable.

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks! That explains it. What about the ones with `-ne` though? Why are they evaluated differently than the ones with `!=`? (i.e. why is an empty string "equal" to "0"/0 with `-ne` but not equal to "0"/0 with `!=`?)

Comment: The [shell arithmetic](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic) section of the manual says: "A null value evaluates to 0."

Comment: #6 is history expansion, and only happens in interactive shells. It prints the matching command from your history and then runs it.

Answer (score 6):

Consider boolean shortcut instead of an `if` statement:

```
is_git_repository || echo you are NOT in a git repo
```